# If you lose me, your life might get harder

Tags: riddle

> I live in a palace where it's dark inside
>   No light in there, unless open wide
>   Even though I am not a king, sometimes I wear a crown
>   I am not a queen either, neither I am a clown
>   I'm known for tearing stuff by moving up and down
>   Don't take care of me and I might hurt you
>   Take care of me and get better pictures of you

Can you guess what am I?

Comment: My dirty mind told me "penis", but the crown did not fit.

Comment: the crown could very well be a condom @Hawker65

Comment: Sorry for triggering your dirty mind @Hawker65!

Comment: @Mario Garcia Indeed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are a:

> tooth!

I live in a palace where it's dark inside
No light in there, unless open wide

> Teeth live in mouths, which fit this description

Even though I am not a king, sometimes I wear a crown
I am not a queen either, neither I am a clown

> Teeth are neither kings, queens, nor clowns, but they do sometimes have [crowns](https://www.aspendental.com/oral-health/oral-health-and-overall-health)

I'm known for tearing stuff by moving up and down

> This describes chewing food

Don't take care of me and I might hurt you

> If you don't brush and floss your teeth, they'll start to hurt!

Take care of me and get better pictures of you

> People like to have a dazzling white smile for photos!

Title:

> Without teeth, it would be harder to eat, which would definitely make life hard!

Comment: This is probably more correct than mine... Mine fits except for the tearing stuff, and this suits that perfectly...

Comment: You're not missing any connection, that line is the follow up of the one before.

Comment: Yay! I finally figured one of these out **BEFORE** looking at the spoilers! :)

Comment: @Vilx- awesome!

Answer (score 5):

I think its

> The brain

I live in a palace where it's dark inside
No light in there, unless open wide

> The skull, a bone palace, is dark inside unless opened up through surgery or injury.

Even though I am not a king, sometimes I wear a crown
I am not a queen either, neither I am a clown

> No gender, but the head could wear a crown (also the crown is part of the head)

I'm known for tearing stuff by moving up and down

> Concussion? Not sure...

Don't take care of me and I might hurt you
Take care of me and get better pictures of you

> Not caring for the head can lead to brain damage, but look after it properly and you'll have a healthier life.

Title:

> Without a brain, life would be pretty hard...